# Hbase snapshot incremental backup

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform, cloudera-cdh

In HBase, we can use ExportSnapshot which will export the snapshot data & metadata to suppose another hbase cluster. So that on the second cluster we'll be able to do "list_snapshots" to check the exported snapshot. And we do clone_snapshot "snapshot_name", "new_table_name" then we can restored the snapshot on the second cluster.

So, is there any method or utility available to take incremental backup of hbase snapshot.let's say 7 days period.

Comment: what do you mean by incremental backup of snapshot? snapshot is a read-only view of a table at given time. you can only take a snapshot of a whole table

Comment: Thanks I got the point now.